# why isn't the z-index working?

Tags: z-index

On [this page](http://tester.doig.com.au/), there are two navigation menus at the top of the page.

One is #topmenu, the one below it is #mainmenu.

#topmenu has a z-index of 200

#mainmenu has a z-index of 100

When I hover over "Depth" in the top menu, and follow the submenu down through Level 01, Level 02, Level 03..., I can't progress past Level 03, because I believe #mainmenu is stealing the pointer's focus.

Why does this happen when #mainmenu has a z-index less than #topmenu?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, z-index only works on positioned elements (absolute, relative, or fixed): http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Both menus have the default positioning (static).

And FYI, there is a bit of space between the levels. If a mouse event happens to get fired there, they all disappear. You'll want to fix that.